# Camara Nativa Ionic 3 Error: Illegal Argument Exception

Tags: android, angular, ionic, cordova

Quiero utilizar este plugin para poder sacar fotos, pero al momento de emularlo en mi celular e inspeccionando su uso, al hacer clic sobre mi botón para capturar la foto me sale el siguiente mensaje y no he podido solucionarlo, alguna ayuda?

la instale como decía la página oficial:

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-camera --variable CAMERA_USAGE_DESCRIPTION="the app need the camera" --variable PHOTOLIBRARY_USAGE_DESCRIPTION="the app need the photolibrary"

npm install @ionic-native/camera --save
```

En mi código HTML:

```
<button ion-button  (click)="sacarFoto()" color="reiterativa">
                    Tomar <br> Foto&nbsp;
                    <ion-icon name="ios-camera-outline" style="font-size:30px;"></ion-icon>
                </button>
                <img [src]="image" *ngIf="image" />
```

en TS:

```
import { Camera, CameraOptions } from '@ionic-native/camera';
.
.
constructor(private camera: Camera....){}
.
.
sacarFoto(){
    let options: CameraOptions = {
      destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
      targetWidth: 1000,
      targetHeight: 1000,
      quality: 100,
      encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
      mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
      saveToPhotoAlbum: true
    }
    this.camera.getPicture( options )
    .then(imageData => {
      this.image = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imageData;
    })
    .catch(error =>{
      console.error( "error detalle: "+error );
    });
  }
```

Finalmente puedo ver por pantalla que pasa enseguida al catch:

```
error detalle: Illegal Argument Exception
```

Lo emulo de la siguiente forma con el celular conectado por USB:

```
ionic cordova run android --prod
```

**EDIT:** Acabo de probar generando la apk: ionic cordova build android --prod
y allí si abre la cámara y permite sacar la foto, pero de igual manera me gustaría hacerlo con el teléfono conectado a través de la emulación para poder ver otros detalles, dado que solo falla en la emulación desde el navegador (chrome)

Answer (score 0):

Lamentablemente no se puede ver desde el emulador ya que es un plugin **nativo**, esto significa que sólo desde un dispositivo real se puede utilizar. La única manera de probarlo es con tu celular o quizás con browser que es para web.

Comment: pero si lo estoy corriendo desde el celular por usb tampoco puedo ver los errores?

Comment: Si lo corres en un dispositivo iOS tienes la consola de xcode para debuguear. Sin embargo, yo te recomiendo testear que todo funcione correctamente y al último el plugin nativo.

Comment: sólo tengo un dispositivo android, la única forma de testear que encontré es generar la apk a cada rato y ver si funciona, pero es una perdida de tiempo tremenda..

Comment: correlo desde consola con ionic cordova run android --livereload --device para que ante cualquier cambio se actualice automáticamente